# What do I need to successfully run a website in my browser that executes Python scripts?

Tags: python, mysql, web

I currently simply have a local website on my Mac. I can view the webpage's HTMl and CSS and run the javascript functions in browser on my computer, but the next step I want to take is incorporating python scripts for accessing a MySQL database and returning results.

I am clearly new to this, and would love some guidance. Right now, on my computer, I have MySQL installed and I can run it in the terminal just fine. What else do I need as far as database and server equipment – if anything – to get some dynamic website running locally? My current, albeit incredibly limited, understanding is that I have a MySQL database stored on my machine that can be accessed through a Python script – also on my machine – and a link to this script in the HTML file. Is this even right, or do you recommend certain tutorials to fill in the gaps or teach me from the ground up?

I am sorry I am asking a lot; the few tutorials I have found have seemed to cover what I am hoping to do. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/)

Comment: just use django,flask,or web2py ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you. I will look into reading up on and finding tutorials on django.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/install/ 
Just follow the installation guide, and you'll be up and running in no time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have MySQL installed on your machine along with Python, get a version of MySQLDb library for Python and have fun with it. Moreover, you can do almost any data operation with these combinations. If you want your website to go live (and do not wish to go through web frameworks) just look for a hosting plan that gives you a Python installed server access.